# Semantic-UI grid: Spanning columns in a grid with different counts per row

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I have a Semantic UI grid with an "odd" number of columns per row:

```
<div class="ui grid">
   <div class="seven column row">
       <div class="column">ABC</div>
       <div class="column">DEF</div>
       <div class="column">GHI</div>
       <div class="column">JKL</div>
       <div class="column">MNO</div>
       <div class="column">PQR</div>
   </div>
```

I would like the "PQR" cell to span two non-standard-sized columns (the last two).

Using "column two wide" does not work.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semantic-UI uses a 16 column grid by default. You can change this for the purpose of your web app by adjusting the [theming variables](http://semantic-ui.com/usage/theming.html).

If you would not like to play around with that, you can use only 14 of the 16 columns and `center align` the grid to have equal space on both left and right side.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/batrasoe/nnpxgmaq/

```
<div class="ui center aligned grid">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="two wide column">ABC</div>
       <div class="two wide column">DEF</div>
       <div class="two wide column">GHI</div>
       <div class="two wide column">JKL</div>
       <div class="two wide column">MNO</div>
       <div class="four wide column">PQR</div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

This uses 2+2+2+2+2+4  = 14 columns

Using something like `<div class="seven column row">` gives the columns equal width. This is why your `two wide column` wouldn't work - as it conflicts the equal width property by saying make the column 2/16 of the width of grid.